# How to send requests parallel to asynchronous services and collect the responses in a Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I develop an application that at some point starts to aggregate an infomation from a bunch of services. Some of that services are called via SOAP interfaces synchronously and some of them works asynchronosly - I have to send a request to JMS queue Q1 and get an answer to Q2 at some point.

The problem is that the app sends requests in one thread and the responses a processed using MDBs (Message-Driven Bean). The solution from the top of my head is to store already aggregated responses in some shared container (like ConcurrentHashMap) with some correlationId. So when an MDB gets a response it looks through the shared container and adds response to the corresponding record.

The app runs on WildFly AS in domain HA mode.

1. Are there some problems that I can run into with this approach? Like the container will be instantiated one for each node in cluster.
2. Or I can accidently process so many requests that I will store so many responses that I will get OutOfMemoryError?
3. What are the best approaches for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer your questions:

1. A response to a JMS service call could arrive anytime (quite soon : the destination server down, the operator take a rest, etc). So you should store the requests in a database during the data aggregation.
2. Performance issues always could happen when you serve many requests parallel. And if you have asynchronous answers you can store many-many hashes for a long time (or with SFSB activate/passivate) till the last answer arrives. The first answer (partly) solve this problem as well, because it stores most of the data in the db and takes just the current ones in the memory. And more robust. The persistent data live survive a server crash/shutdown.
3. When you need the data, create a db entry for all and send out the requests with its PK in the header. When an answer arrives, its header contains the same PK for the identification. The MDBs are best way to receive them. But use them just to receive the messages. Process its contents by EJBs. Delegate the message contents synchronously to the EJB(s) and acknowledge them according to the EJB answers. At the very end of the EJB processing fetch the IDs of the unprocessed requests belong to the current aggregation. If there is no one, (remove the query entries from the db table and) call the appropriate EJB (via MDB?) to proceed the work with the fulfilled data needs.

Comment: What's the point of delegating work to the ejb? I won'y be able to acknowledge the message until the ejb is done anyway. Also i can't store the ids because it's not something with id it is a result of calculating. So I should save the full object.

Comment: The EJB processing is synchronous, the message acknowledgment depends on the EJB method result. The ID is the primary key of the table, sent and passed back (MDB) by the JMS messages.

Comment: although there is some sense in your words I don't think you understand the question right

Comment: You asked in your question : what is the best (better) solution? I think my answer takes place in this set

Comment: When MDB calls EJB it will be blocked until the EJB is done. So it's not important that mdb is asynchronous and it's no difference will I do smth in mdb or in session bean or else.

Comment: The remote calls (who knows how long it will run) are asynch ones. The local calls are synch ones. it metters.

Comment: Aren't the remote calls were made to call ejbs from Client to the server? why will I do the remote call from server to server. More than that it can run long but to acknowledge the message from queue you have to wait until the ejb returns (who knows it went without exception) or you will ack. the bad processing.

Comment: there is a req (synch.) from the user to aggregate data. this ejb pawn a thread to send the JMS (asynch) messages into the request queue. The MDBs do their works and sent back their JMS (asynch) messages into the response queue. The MDBs delegate the responses to EJBs. They process them in the way detailed above (DB operations). After the last response arrived, calls an EJB (synch.) to process the aggregated data and notify the client (by email,..) about the results. This is the way it works most of the cases.

Comment: the client could wait for the response but a timeout is a good chance possibility if there is an asynch call in the process